# Android Java how to change fontFamily of a TextView programmatically to a font not in the res/font folder

Tags: java, android, android-layout, fonts, android-fonts

I know I can set the `fontFamily` of a `TextView` using the following:

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(MainActivity.getAppContext(), R.font.roboto_medium);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

But I think that only works because my project has the corresponding res/font/roboto.medium.xml file.

I noticed that in Android Studio I can specify a `fontFamily` that is downloadable and generates a .ttf file in the res/font folder. Can my app use an externally loaded .ttf file at runtime? For example, can I load and use a font from the `/system/fonts` directory of an Android device?

My app needs to read in a configuration file that contains the `fontFamily` to be used for certain `TextViews`. Do I have to ensure that all fonts that the configuration file can specify already exist in the res/font folder?

Or is it possible to change the `fontFamily` used in a `TextView` to a font not listed in the res/font resource folder at the time the application was generated? If so, how is it done?

Comment: So where is the font, in asset folder?

Comment: @EliasFazel my single font for the app is currently defined in the resources / font directory of the project.

Comment: check out this guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts

Comment: @EliasFazel thank you for that link!